# Javascript não carrega função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um arquivo javascript '**cep**'. onde tem um método chamado exibe(); mas quando eu executo este método no meu arquivo atual que está na página ao lado de HTML, ele não funciona, por quê?

**cep.js**

```
$ (document).ready(function () {
     function exibe()
     {
          alert ('Hello');
     }
  });
```

**index.html**

```
HTML
.
.
.

@section ('page-script')
<script src = "{{asset ('js/cep.js')}}"> </ script>
   $ (document).ready(function () {                    
             exibe();    
   });

</ script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque você declarou sua função dentro de outra, e não no escopo global. Faça assim:

**cep.js**

```
function exibe()
{
     alert ('Hello');
}
```